# How to upgrade to Windows 8.1 but keep the files

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, windows-installation, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1. I have a lot of data stored in my PC, It would be very tedious to back up all of the data.
I have stored the data in local disks other than the system files containing disk (local disk: C), so is there any way to uninstall Windows 7 and upgrade it to newer OS without deleting any of my personal data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like you’re ready to go. Back up any personal data that’s still on the Windows disk, and the Windows installer will only touch the disk that you tell it to.

Comment: I am afraid, won't the disk partitions get lost and therefore files on the hard disk get erased during installation?

Comment: Because the disk has already been partitioned (100MB system reserved + Windows system + your data partition) the installer will only install to the partition you stipulate in the installer. If your data is on a completely separate physical hard disk then I would recommend disconnecting this prior to installing Windows 8.1 to remove it from the equation. As svenper says, any important data within the Windows partition that you need then back this up too, prior to formatting. I wound recommend a clean install after this if you can.

Comment: @user70856 - No? Windows 7 to Windows 8.0 upgrade is fully supported.  Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 will require you to only reinstall your applications.

Comment: Yes you can upgrade. I would just warn you about backups, even if it's tedious you should consider backuping your data on external media on a regular basis.